# Prove that $\log(\max(\left | z_1 \right |,\left | z_2 \right |,\ldots,\left | z_n \right |)) \in MPSH(\Omega)$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables, potential-theory

This's an example:

*For $u(z_1,z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\log(\max(\left | z_1 \right |,\left | z_2 \right |,\ldots,\left | z_n \right |))$, where $z=(z_1,z_1,\ldots,z_n) \in \Omega=\mathbb{C}^n \setminus\{0\} $. Prove that $u \in MPSH(\Omega)$*.

And here's the solution in my textbook:

$\bullet$  Suppose that $v \in PSH(\Omega)$, $G \subset \subset \Omega$ and $v \le u$ on $\partial G$.
For all $z \in G$, we consider an open set $A=\{t \in \mathbb{C}: tz \in G\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

We have $u(tz)$ and $v(tz)=\log\left | t \right |+\log(\max(\left | z_1 \right |,\left | z_2 \right |,\ldots,\left | z_n \right |)) \in PSH(\Omega), \forall z=(z_1,z_1,\ldots,z_n) $.

Moreover, $\partial A \subset \partial G$. Hence, $v(tz)|_{\partial A} \le u(tz)|_{\partial A}$.

Because $u$ be a harmonic then  $v(tz)|_{A} \le u(tz)|_{A}$.

Therefore, $v(z) \le u(z)$ in $G$.////

But I don't understand the solution above. Ex Why we have $\partial A \subset \partial G$? Why $v(tz)|_{\partial A} \le u(tz)|_{\partial A}$?

Can anyone help me (explain clearly)! Thanks.

Comment: What is $MPSH$ and $PSH$?

Comment: $\bullet$PSH:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurisubharmonic_function $\bullet$ MPSH: Maximal PluriSubHarmonic function :)

Answer (score 1):

The statement $\partial A \subset \partial G$ makes no sense. ($A \subset \mathbb{C}$ but $G \subset \mathbb{C}^n$). But if $z \in G$ is fixed and $t\in\partial A$, then $tz \in \partial G$, which is probably what is meant.

By assumption, $v \le u$ on $\partial G$, so $v(tz) \le u(tz)$ for $t \in \partial A$. Finally $t \mapsto v(tz)$ is subharmonic and $t \mapsto u(tz) = \log|t| + \log\{\max|z_1|,\ldots,|z_n|\}$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. By definition of subharmonicity, $v(tz) \le u(tz)$ for $t \in A$. In particular, $1 \in A$, so $v(z) \le u(z)$. But since $z \in G$ was arbitrary, $v \le u$ on $G$, showing that $u$ is indeed maximal.

Comment: $\bullet$ Your explanation makes me understand my problem. You're really good (y). Thanks **mrf**. $\bullet$ And of course, before we show $u$ is a maximal function, then we need $u \in PSH(\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\})$, because $\max(\left | z_1 \right |,\left | z_2 \right |,\ldots,\left | z_n \right |) \in PSH(\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\}) $ and $\log \left |f \right| \in PSH(\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\})$, with $|f| \in PSH(\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\})$.

Comment: And still you neither upvote nor accept answers. Please start learning how this site works.

Comment: By the way, $u$ is psh on the whole of $\mathbb{C}^n$, but it's only maximal on $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: $\bullet$ Until you say, I have noticed vote button, hihi :) . I voted for your answer.  $\bullet$ Btw, you're right! We can show that $u \not \in MPSH(\mathbb{C^n})$.

Comment: You have not voted on my answer or on anybody else's. You also have not yet accepted a single answer to any of the questions you have asked.

Comment: Can you tell me how to vote? I clicked the "**votes**" button. Actually, your answer is great (y) , you deserve any thing more than that.

Comment: @kimtahe6 To vote, click the uparrow to the left of the questions and answers (or the downarrow to downvote). See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for information about accepting answers to your own questions.

Comment: Now, that's Ok. Until today, I have had about what you said (click the uparrow), I'm sorry I hadn't known that, hihi.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

$\bigstar$ We'll prove that $u \in MPSH(\Omega)$, where $\Omega=\Bbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\}$.

- We have$$\begin{align*} \\
  \log \left |z_j  \right |\in PSH(\Omega), \forall j=\overline{1,n} &\implies \max\left \{ \log \left |z_j  \right | \right \}\in PSH(\Omega),\forall j=\overline{1,n}\\ &\implies u=\log\left ( \max\left \{ \left | z_1 \right |,\ldots,\left | z_n \right | \right \} \right )\in PSH(\Omega) \end{align*}$$
  $\bigstar$ With $v \in PSH(\Omega)$, $G \subset  \subset \Omega, v$ is upper - semicontinuous in $\overline{G}$ and $v \le u$ on $\partial G$. We'll prove that $v \le u $ in $G$.
- Take $\omega \in G$ was arbitrary. We consider $A=\left \{ t\in \Bbb C: t\omega \in G \right \}$.

We have $\forall t_0 \in A\implies t_0\omega\in G\implies \exists B_{\Bbb C^n}(t_0\omega,r)\subset G$.

On the other hand, $$\forall t \in B_{\Bbb C}\left ( t_0,\dfrac{r}{\left |\omega  \right |} \right )\implies \left | t-t_0 \right |\left | \omega \right |<r \implies \left | t\omega - t_0\omega \right |<r\implies t\omega\in G \implies t \in A$$

So, $t_0\in B_{\Bbb C}\left ( t_0,\dfrac{r}{\left |\omega  \right |} \right )\subset A$.

Therefore, $A$ is an open set.

- We have $v(t\omega) \in SH(A)$, because $v \in PSH(\Omega) $
- We have $u(t\omega)\in SH(A)$. Indeed:

We have $$\begin{align*} \\ u(t\omega)&=\log\left | t \right |+\log\left ( \max\left \{ \left | \omega_1 \right |,\ldots, \left | \omega_n \right |\right \} \right )\\&=Re \log t + \log\left ( \max\left \{ \left | \omega_1 \right |,\ldots, \left | \omega_n \right |\right \} \right )\in SH(A)\end{align*}$$

- We'll show that $v(t\omega) \le u(t\omega), \forall t \in \partial A$.

Indeed, we take $t \in \partial A\implies \exists \left \{ t_n \right \}\subset A, t_n \to t \in \Bbb C\implies t_n \omega \to t\omega \in \Bbb C^n$.

Moreover, because $\left \{ t_n \omega \right \}\subset G \implies t \omega \in \overline{G}\overset{t \omega \notin {G}}{\rightarrow}t \omega \in  \partial G$.

Therefore, $v(t\omega) \le u(t\omega), \forall t \in \partial A$.

Now, we let $$h(t):=v(t\omega)-u(t\omega)\in SH(A)$$
We have $h$ is upper - semicontinuous in $\overline{A}$ - compact. So, $\exists t_0 \in \overline{A}$ such that $$h(t_0)=\max_{t \in \overline{A}} h(t)$$

- If $t_0 \in A \implies h\mid_\Omega=0$
- If $t_0 \in \partial A \implies \lim_{t \to \xi} \sup h(t) \le h(t_0), \forall \xi \in \partial A \implies h \le 0$  in $A \implies v(t \omega ) \le u (t \omega )$ in $A$.

In particular, $1 \in A$, we take $t=1$ then $v(\omega ) \le u (\omega )$.

However, since $\omega \in G$ was arbitrary, $v \le u$ on $G$, showing that $u$ is indeed maximal $\blacksquare $.

=======================================

@**mrf**: My solution is correct?

Can you help me show that $u \notin MPSH(\Bbb C^n)$? Thanks!